# Is there a word or term for one who is obsessed with names?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is for a piece I am currently writing. Since I could not find anything from a Google search, I figured it would be wise to enlist the knowledge of the smart cohort of Stack Exchange.

My question is simple - is there a term for one who has an obsession with names or naming, or perhaps even the act of applying labels to some unnamed entity?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: "smart guys and gals of StackExchange". I like that :)

Comment: @TusharRaj -- " "Flattery will get you nowhere, but don't stop."

Comment: We just call 'em *onomasts*; it's not necessary to include the obsessive part in the term, because it's implied by the fact that they're onomasts in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The appropriate word or a phrase might depend on the context, that is the sort of piece you are writing. For someone who gives names:

[**nomenclaturist**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nomenclaturist) which redirects to M-W 3rd definition of

[**nomenclator**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nomenclator):

> 3:  one who gives names to or invents names for things

*Nomenclator* is also a book that contains names or lists of words (and most examples of usage refer to this meaning); in the sense that we need here there are more [examples of usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=nomenclaturist&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&q=%22nomenclaturist%22)* for nomenclaturist:

> *The aspiring taxonomist or nomenclaturist used to have little choice but to become an obsessive-compulsive book and reprint collector, and had to visit major libraries in large cities on a regular basis to consult rare and obscure books and journals that survived in only a few of the larger depositories.*

From: [Marine Algae: Biodiversity, Taxonomy, Environmental Assessment, and Biotechnology](https://books.google.rs/books?id=LuysBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA358&dq=%22nomenclaturist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pVRkVZ_qBqKvygPp74HgCw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22nomenclaturist%22&f=false)
 edited by Leonel Pereira, Joao Magalhaes Neto

If you need someone who coins and deals with technical terms, ODO gives this example of usage for a

[**terminologist**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terminology?q=terminologist#terminology__14)

> *The terminologist drafts definitions and recommends the adoption of new terms for standardization purposes.*

Since giving names is often tied with classification, another appropriate word might be:

[**taxonomist**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/taxonomy?q=taxonomist#taxonomy__21) who is not just someone interested/working in the field of:

> the classification of something, especially organisms (ODO)

but also someone who [*created a tag used by 50 questions*](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges) on SE (and a tag is a sort of a label, so our taxonomists create labels and assign them to posts).

---

To convey the obsession or extensive work in the field of name-giving you might need either a neologism or a phrase:

[**The Name Giver**](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2007/06/linnaeus-name-giver/david-quammen-text) is how National Geographic refers to Carl Linnaeus, describing not just his vast contribution to plant nomenclature and taxonomy, but also a situation from his family:

> *The child's father, Nils Linnaeus, was an amateur botanist and an avid gardener as well as a Lutheran minister, who **had concocted his own surname** (a bureaucratic necessity for university enrollment, replacing his traditional patronymic, son of Ingemar) from the Swedish word lind, meaning linden tree.*

So the art of creating names obviously ran in the family there.

Sometimes less is more so an ordinary:

**name obsessed** might to.

But if you would like to go the extra mile, you might borrow The Philolexian Society's term:

[**Nomenclaturist General**](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/philo/nomenclaturist_general/)

---

*beware of the false positives: nomenclaturist can be an adjective derived from *nomenclaturism*

Comment: What is nomenclaturism (so that we should be wary of it)?

Comment: @Mitch I'm not sure but I ran into this: [Saussurean. anti-nomenclaturism. in. grammatical. analysis](https://books.google.rs/books?id=QvSXLwDSFHcC&pg=PA398&dq=%22nomenclaturist%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kHJkVZGrMqbOygPm04DgDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22nomenclaturism%22&f=false) and a few similar texts, where 'nomenclaturist' is not a person but an attribute for a linguistic... something (viewpoint or school of thought perhaps).

Comment: None of the words you mention are used "in the field", in my experience. The standard/usual word for the science or study of names is _onomastics_, but the usual term in name enthusiast circles is, well, _name enthusiast_ (often abbreviated to NE).

Comment: @JPmiaou I agree that these terms may not be widely used, but the OP doesn't say that wide usage is what they are after. They also didn't specify the sort of piece they are writing - in some texts one can get creative, like people from National Geographic :-). In any case I like your suggestion 'name enthusiast': indeed enthusiasts sometimes get obsessed - consider expanding it in an answer :-).

Answer (score 4):

"A preoccupation with words or names" is *[onomatomania](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onomatomania)*, so the word for such a person would be *onomatophile* or even *onomatomaniac*.

(This whole discussion might onomatomaniacally [autological](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/autological).)

**EDIT**: [Martha](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/1547/martha%C2%AA) suggests *onomast*, which is a "real" word in the sense that people other than me use it (if you want to resort to that definition) but does not, I don't think, conveys the idea of *obsession*.  More of a sensible expert.

Comment: Can you please provide some reference to the nouns you are suggesting?

Comment: Since the fear of names is regularly formed from the declinational stem of _όνομα_ (a t-stem) as _onomatophobia_, its opposite ought to be _onomatophilia_, too. Neither version seems to be in actual use, though.

Comment: @Josh61 -- I am pretty sure the earliest use is [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/248563/4040).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet -- duly edited.

Comment: ***onomatomania*** - obsession with a particular word which the person uses repeatedly or which intrudes into consciousness. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/onomatomania

Comment: @Josh61 -- Could there be a more perfect example of [Cunningham's Law](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law)?

Comment: @Malvolio - yeah, but you can still improve your answer with appropriate reference. :)

Comment: @Josh61  -- duly edited.